# Trouble with adding series name in Highcharts with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, highcharts

Data in the CSV/txt file looks like this:-

```
Installation,Manufacturing, Sales & Distribution,Project Development,Other
43934,  24916,  11744,  0,  12908
52503,  24064,  17722,  0,  5948
57177,  29742,  16005,  7988,   8105
69658,  29851,  19771,  12169,  11248
97031,  32490,  20185,  15112,  8989
119931, 30282,  24377,  22452,  11816
137133, 38121,  32147,  34400,  18274
154175, 40434,  39387,  34227,  18111
```

In order to create the data series In Highchart, I have used the following code, which work perfectly well.

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv
from highcharts import Highchart

FileName = "C:/Users/kesid/Documents/Pthon/Pthon.csv"
FileName1 = "C:/ExcelP/Highcharts_Test.html"

H = Highchart()

data = pd.read_csv(FileName).T

#creating list for series
Row_list =[]

for i in range((data.shape[0])): 

    # Using iloc to access the values of  
    # the current row denoted by "i" 
    Row_list.append(list(zip(data.iloc[i, :]))) 

print(Row_list)
```

At this point, Row_list result looks like this:-

```
[[(43934,), (52503,), (57177,), (69658,), (97031,), (119931,), (137133,), (154175,)], [(24916,), (24064,), (29742,), (29851,), (32490,), (30282,), (38121,), (40434,)], [(11744,), (17722,), (16005,), (19771,), (20185,), (24377,), (32147,), (39387,)], [(0,), (0,), (7988,), (12169,), (15112,), (22452,), (34400,), (34227,)], [(12908,), (5948,), (8105,), (11248,), (8989,), (11816,), (18274,), (18111,)]]
```

Now, adding those series to Highchart

```
for i, series in enumerate(Row_list):
       H.add_data_set(series,
                series_type='line',
                name= "series_%d" % i) 

# write out the html
with open(FileName1, "wt") as fh:
    fh.write(H.htmlcontent)
```

The problem is that chart names are appearing like "Series_1", "Series_2"... But how should I make it like Installation, Manufacturing, etc? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Siddalmia22, What is the final result of your series structure?

Comment: Hi, the final structure is like this "file:///C:/ExcelP/Highcharts_Test.html". Not sure if you can open this. But it's a line chart and all work good except the series name. I want to show name of series same as the header of the column data

Comment: And what is the representation of the series in this file?

Comment: you can see the lines basically they are the series. the name of those series are Series_0, Series_1, Series_2. this is based on the index in the data

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know Python well, but you probably need to create an array from the first row of the csv file and assign the names in the loop: `name= "series_%d" % i) `

Comment: thanks mate, I did the same earlier but it passes series name multiple times.